# QueryException on Hibernate when using CriteriaBuilder.function()

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I was trying to do a simple select using JPA:

```
SELECT POW(2, 10) FROM COUNTRY
```

So, I give it a try:

```
EntityManager em = getEM();
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder( );
CriteriaQuery< Object > cq = cb.createQuery( );
cq.from( Country.class );
cq.multiselect( cb.function( "POW", Integer.class, cb.literal( 2 ), cb.literal( 10 ) ) );
em.createQuery( cq ).getResultList( );
```

And this gives me back a `QueryException`:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode
\-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: 'function (POW)'
    +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'POW' {originalText=POW}
    \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
        +-[NUM_INT] LiteralNode: '2'
        \-[NUM_INT] LiteralNode: '10'
[select function('POW', 2, 10) from model.Country as generatedAlias0]
```

Then, I tried to cast it:

```
EntityManager em = getEM();
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder( );
CriteriaQuery< Object > cq = cb.createQuery( );
cq.from( Country.class );
cq.multiselect( cb.function( "POW", Integer.class, cb.literal( 2 ), cb.literal( 10 ) ).as( Long.class ) );
em.createQuery( cq ).getResultList( );
```

(I have tried to cast it as String and Long. Casting to Integer results in the same exception as above.)

And then I get another QueryException:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: CAST function should only have 2 arguments [select cast(function('POW', 2, 10) as string) from model.Country as generatedAlias0]
[...]
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:655)
... 31 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: CAST function should only have 2 arguments
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.SqlGenerator$CastFunctionArguments.betweenFunctionArguments(SqlGenerator.java:300)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.SqlGenerator.betweenFunctionArguments(SqlGenerator.java:137)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.SqlGeneratorBase.methodCall(SqlGeneratorBase.java:2584)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.SqlGeneratorBase.selectExpr(SqlGeneratorBase.java:2130)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.SqlGeneratorBase.selectColumn(SqlGeneratorBase.java:1942)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.SqlGeneratorBase.selectClause(SqlGeneratorBase.java:555)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.SqlGeneratorBase.selectStatement(SqlGeneratorBase.java:197)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.SqlGeneratorBase.statement(SqlGeneratorBase.java:146)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.generate(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:248)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:209)
... 37 more
```

What am I doing wrong?

P.S.: I tried the above query with EclipseLink and it works fine.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code (without the cast since it specifies the return type, or with the cast). Raise a bug (or two) on your JPA provider

Comment: Bug opened: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11938
Thank you, @NeilStockton

Comment: Thanks @NeilStockton ! Please, could you also check my answer to this question?

Comment: No, I cannot do that since I don't use Hibernate. I use a JPA provider that works on the query you presented (DataNucleus)

Comment: OK @NeilStockton ! Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by a member of Hibernate organization, this problem will be addressed on version 6.0+.

But he stated that there's a work around. If you have this problem, you need to declare the function at the Dialect level:

```
// Extends on the best dialect for your case
public class NewDialect extends MySQLDialect {

    public NewDialect( ) {
        registerFunction( "POW", new StandardSQLFunction( "POW", StandardBasicTypes.DOUBLE ) );
    }
}

// In your hibernate config: (assuming you are using StandardServiceRegistryBuilder)
ssrb.applySetting( "hibernate.dialect", "com.example.NewDialect" );
```

Reference: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11938